# Django static import on template

Tags: css, django

I'm trying to import a css file on my template.

Here is the hierachy:

```
-mega_series
   -mega_series
   -series
      -models.py
      -static
         -series
            -css
               -style.css
      ...
   -manage.py
   -media
      -covers
   -static
```

Here is how I import it:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="{% static "series/css/style.css" %}"/>
```

In settings.py I have it:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Why isn't the css loaded?

Comment: Have you defined your static files directory in **settings.py** ?

Comment: What do you mean with static files directory? i only have STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT defined.

Comment: I told to add **STATIC_ROOT** after STATIC_URL like that `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: Yes, I have like this: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: why there is another folder name static?

Comment: I have a global static folder, and specific static folder for each application in project. Is it wrong?

Comment: No it's not wrong. Absolutely normal. Although `STATIC_ROOT ` is better to name `static_root` in case you have your project's `static` directory, which Django will search automatically.

Comment: Is there a directory `series/css` inside global static dir?

Comment: No, global static dir has: css/style.css and series static  dir has: series/css/style.css

Comment: Finally it's working. I've just remove it and rewritten. Probably there was anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import will be like that:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "series/css/style.css" %}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps! :)

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% get_static_prefix %}series/css/style.css" />
```

in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR ='%s'%(path_to_mega_series)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and your STATIC_ROOT